# Why is my clojure loop returning single letters instead of whole words?

Tags: loops, clojure

I'm attempting to loop through a set of strings, stripping excess text. It works, but too well. Given input like this:

```
#{"TORCASO,133114,117,0.04,89045.38,99.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00" "POTOCZNY,98770,170,0.06,87231.39,98.82,0.00,(S),0.00,0.00,(S)"}
```

My output looks like this:

```
#{\A \C \N \O \P \R \S \T \Y \Z}
```

But I expected it to look like this:

```
#{"TORCASO" "POTOCZNY"}
```

Here's my code:

```
(defn shorten-string
  [string]
  (first (str/split string #",")))


(defn handle-csv
  [strings]
  (loop [remaining-strings strings final-set #{}]
   (if (empty? remaining-strings)
     final-set
     (let [[part & remaining] remaining-strings]
       (recur remaining
              (into final-set
                    (shorten-string part)))))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `loop / recur` for looping should be your last resort- there is usually some better function. In this case, you should use [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map):

```
(def data #{"TORCASO,133114,117,0.04,89045.38,99.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00" "POTOCZNY,98770,170,0.06,87231.39,98.82,0.00,(S),0.00,0.00,(S)"})

(defn shorten-string [string]
  (first (clojure.string/split string #",")))

(defn handle-csv [strings]
  (->> strings
       (map shorten-string)
       (into #{})))
```

([`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) is thread-last macro)

Example:

```
(handle-csv data)
=> #{"TORCASO" "POTOCZNY"}
```

Comment: Yet I'd rather use the transducer version instead `(into #{} (map shorten-string) strings))`

Comment: The three basic methods - map, filter, reduce. Always better to use these if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently using "into" was the problem, as I was attempting to put a string into a set, so I should have been using conj or cons.

Comment: Yes, `into` expects a collection, so it was treating your string like a sequence of characters.